# Instascan select back camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qr-code

I have a website where the users should be available to scan QR codes using their mobile phones. I'm using the library instascan.

For example, the mobile phone I amb using for testing the website has 4 back cameras (huawei p30 pro).

I have implmented a for each that selects the first 'back' camera:

```
if (cameras.length > 0) {
  var selectedCam = cameras[0];
  $.each(cameras, (i, c) => {
    if (c.name.indexOf('back') != -1) {
      selectedCam = c;
      return false;
    }
  });
  scanner.start(selectedCam);

else {
  console.error('No cameras found.');
}
```

Doing that way the first back camera found the vision is so fuzzy and I can't scan the QR. If I select by default the second camera for example by doing:

`scanner.start(cameras[2]);`

the vision is perfect and I can scan all the QR.

My questions is if anyone know a generic way to pick the correct back camera, or the 'main' back camera?

I mean my website is going to be used by so many users that will have differents mobile phones so they will have different numbers of cameras. That includes that the order of cameras will not be always the same.

Comment: There's no way to know which is the 'main' back camera. Your best option is to make it easy for people to select which camera on their device they want to use (assuming multiple are available)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that is impossible to get the main camera. Any idea of how to do that select? thanks

Comment: The same code is being shared here https://github.com/schmich/instascan/issues/33. If It's a specific case to some mobile phones, why not inspecting user agent and change the script to handle specific phones separately... ?

Comment: @Bilel This website will be used for museum workers to scan the qr codes from the customers tickets. So I can't inspect the mobile phones of all the workers.

Comment: Nobody can :) By inspecting I mean detecting user' browser' User Agent ! To identify the mobile brand via it's browser... If the mobile brand is known to have specific camera types, the app script would handle it appropriately. It's like the old wap versions that used to treat mobile phones differently.  The effort is to make a research looking for exceptional brands :)

Comment: You can use something like this : https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js